# Completely uninstall an application

Tags: macos

Is there a way to completely delete an application from my Macbook? I don't mean to just save the space by deleting it from the applications folder, but to delete all the files that it uses to make it run. I don't worry about the files it produces.

Answer (score 7):

There are several 3rd-party “un-installers” available for Mac. The one I use is [AppZapper](http://www.appzapper.com).

There may be files in "~/Library/Application Support/{folder name of app}" and there may be a preference file in ~/Library/Preferences/.

Sandboxed apps have their data in "~/Library/Containers/{folder name of company}"

Some applications may also install more complicated things like kexts. Most of those apps will have their own uninstallers.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the application from the Applications folder *is* deleting the application.  Some will store further data in `~/Library/Application\ Support/`.

Answer (score 2):

Well known you can go ahead and download "AppCleaner". Find it here : http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/ [Supports OS X 10.6 - 10.9 Currently]
[image]

Here's another way to delete some apps.

When you install a application, many of them will come when you click "**Launchpad**" To delete a app try doing this :

1 : Click Launchpad

[image]

2 : Click and hold the app you want to delete [ NEXT CLICK ON THAT X LITTLE BUTTON TO DELETE YOUR APP ]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ask your question before. Really, the best way to delete application is (if you can't remove this app by simple 'x'-button pressed) ["AppCleaner"](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25276/appcleaner/)

Yes, you can manually delete these files from Application Support folder or from Library/Containters folder.

But...
You will have unexpected result.

Just a one example (not related to deleting apps, but related to command line usage and os x).

I have experience in command line usage, but, after prompt command 'purge' in OS X, which will give me more free RAM, I gain only a headache, because my XCode app becomes insane.

So, be sure in what you will do.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm using Clean My Mac

> Clean, optimize, and maintain your Mac with the all-new CleanMyMac 3.
>   It scans every inch of your system, removes gigabytes of junk in just
>   two clicks, and monitors the health of your Mac.

As you can see on the image below, CleanMyMac is providing you a list of your applications and it's showing you all the files that will be deleted.
[image]

https://macpaw.com/cleanmymac