# deleting app from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, applications

from the /Applications folder, I can launch apps on my Mac using the `open` command in the terminal like this

```
open xcode.app
open firefox.app
```

Is there a way to delete apps from the terminal? [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116755/delete-an-app-from-macbook) question/answer doesn't provide the answer to this question

Comment: are you looking for more than `rm -r firefox.app` ?

Comment: @dwightk it did occur to me that I could use that command, just wondered if there was a specific Apple command

Answer (score 5):

This isn't built into OSX, but a guy wrote a cli tool called `trash` that is cross platform and is intended as a safe alternative to `rm`. As it seems it should, it moves the target to the trash rather than deleting it immediately.

There is more information and instructions on how to install at the [trash github page](https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash)

Answer (score 2):

It is [not recommended](http://www.macworld.com/article/1048263/rmdangers.html) to use the `rm` method since you can mistakenly remove wrong file and it is no longer in trash.

But if you must:

Instructions

> Type `sudo rm –f`  (with a space after the f and not including the
>   quotes) to delete a file.
>
> Type `sudo rm –rf`  to delete a folder.
>
> Drag and drop the files you wish to delete onto the open Terminal
>   window. The files you drop on the Terminal window will be deleted. You
>   can drag and drop multiple files and folders onto the Terminal window.

Read more: http://www.ehow.com/how_4530950_delete-terminal-mac-os-x.html#ixzz324fT3H5z

YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED !

Comment: You don't need sudo with `rm` if you wouldn't need to enter your password when deleting it in Finder. Also, I would recommend reading [the rm man page](http://ss64.com/osx/rm.html) instead of eHow…

Answer (score -3):

- use `sudo rm "filename.extension"` for removing a file
- use `sudo rm -r "folder name"` for removing a folder with all
  sub-folders
- use `sudo rm -ir "foldername or filename.extension"` for safe
  removal.

Note:

- `rm` command removes all files/folders permanently.
- Instead of typing the name of a file or a folder, drag and drop the
  files you wish to delete onto the open Terminal window (after typing
  one of the above commands). The files you drop on the Terminal
  window will be deleted. You can drag and drop multiple files and
  folders onto the Terminal window.

Comment: This doesn’t differ from the existing answer regarding `rm` in any significant way and appears to be an instruction guide on how to use `rm` rather than removing an app as per the OP